# How to change date format in CSV file using windows cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, datetime-format

I have a csv file downloaded from salesforce dataloader and I want to change the date format of Last Modified date (YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z) to (YYYY-MM-DD) using windows cmd.

I tried referring an old link ([Changing datetime format in csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595779/changing-datetime-format-in-csv-files)). I am new to windows cmd and I didn't understand the batch script completely there.

Here is the batch script code which I am trying.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('TestCSV1.csv') do (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3* delims=," %%i in ("%%~fx") do (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command \"{YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z}\" -f [datetime]^('%%k'^)') do >>"TestCSV2.csv" echo %%i,%%j, %%a
    )
)
```

And this the CSV file in which I have to make changes.

```
FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,LASTMODIFIEDDATE,PHONE
Test,Last1,2019-01-21T19:07:36.000Z,9876543210
Test,Last2,2019-01-21T19:07:45.000Z,9876543211
Test,Last3,2019-01-22T05:56:20.000Z,9876543212
```

Need some help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that none of the fields of the CSV file is empty, the following script would do what you want:

```vb
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_CSV=%~1"
set "_SEP=,"

set "HEAD="
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=%_SEP% eol=%_SEP%" %%A in ("%_CSV%") do (
    if not defined HEAD (
        echo(%%A%_SEP%%%B%_SEP%%%C%_SEP%%%D
        set "HEAD=#"
    ) else (
        for /F "delims=T eol=T" %%E in ("%%C") do (
            echo(%%A%_SEP%%%B%_SEP%%%E%_SEP%%%D
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Assuming it is called `change-date.bat`, run it and provide the CSV file as command line argument:

```vb
change-date.bat "TestCSV1.csv"
```

If you want to save the result in another file, use this:

```vb
change-date.bat "TestCSV1.csv" > "TestCSV2.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works but you have to remove the header from your input file first.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b TestCSV1.csv') do (
 for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4* delims=," %%i in ("%%~fx") do (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command \"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}\" -f [datetime]^('%%k'^)') do >>"%%~nx_new.csv" echo %%i,%%j,%%a,%%l
 )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Vlam, but it didn't work. I have tried removing the headers as well.

Comment: I have tried and it works for me. What results did you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved version of Vlam's code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "file=testCSV1.csv"

for %%x in ("%file%") do (
  <"%%~fx" set /p "Header="
  (
    echo !Header!
    for /f "skip=1 usebackq tokens=1-4* delims=," %%i in ("%%~fx") do (
      REM for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command \"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}\" -f [datetime]^('%%k'^)') do echo %%i,%%j,%%a,%%l
      set "day=%%k"
      echo %%i,%%j,!day:~0,10!,%%l
    )
  )>"%%~nx_new.csv"
)
```

It copies the first line of the original file (the Header) to a variable for further use and the `for` loop processes the rest (`skip=1`). I replaced the (working) Powershell code (commented out) with a much faster substring processing. Also I redirect the whole output in one go, which also speeds things up a lot (noticeable with larger files).

Answer (score 0):

It is even easier in PowerShell.

```
Import-Csv -Path '.\fixd.csv' |
    ForEach-Object {$_.LASTMODIFIEDDATE=$_.LASTMODIFIEDDATE.Substring(0, 10); $_} |
    Export-Csv -Path '.\fixdnew.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you must run from cmd.exe:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Import-Csv -Path '.\fixd.csv' |" ^
    "ForEach-Object {$_.LASTMODIFIEDDATE=$_.LASTMODIFIEDDATE.Substring(0, 10); $_} |" ^
    "Export-Csv -Path '.\fixdnew.csv' -NoTypeInformation"
```